# How to filter the selected checkbox using angularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, loops, lodash

Listed all the array of object as a lists using ng-repeat and added checkbox for each value.

Here I want to filter the checkbox and form a new JSON on click **Apply Filter** based on check/uncheck the value(Checkbox's).

**Actual**

I've tried adding the selected and unselected checkbox in the models scope object($scope.models) by concatenating the filter name and its values

**(i.e) : data1(filter name)+1(value) = data11**

On clicking **apply filter** looping the existing filters array and compare with the model object and push the matches in the new array.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QwgMIY7k70WkPW7lcQw7?p=preview)

**Apply Filter function**

**HTML**

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, filter) in filters">
<a href="" data-target="#{{filter.name}}" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="{{enableShow.indexOf(filter.name) > -1 ? true : false}}">
    {{filter.name}}
</a>
<ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="{{filter.name}}" ng-class="{show : enableShow.indexOf(filter.name) > -1}">
    <li ng-repeat="v in filter.values">
        <label class="w-100" ng-show="filter.type == 'CheckBox'">
            <span class="ml-3 p-1 d-block">
                {{v.value}}
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="models[filter.name + v.value]" class="pull-right mt-1 ml-1" style="margin-right: 7%" />
            </span>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.applyFilters = function() {
var arr = [];
_.map($scope.filters, function(d) {
    _.map(d.values, function(v) {
        var name = d.name + v.value;
        for (key in $scope.models) {
            if (key == name) {
                arr.push({
                    name: d.name,
                    values: v
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
console.log(arr);
};
```

**Expected**

On clicking apply filter want to form a new JSON which contains only the selected values in its respective object.

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "name": "data1",
        "type": "CheckBox",
        "values": [
            {
                "value": "1"
            },
            {
                "value": "4"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "data2",
        "type": "CheckBox",
        "values": [
            {
                "value": "1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "data5",
        "type": "CheckBox",
        "values": [
            {
                "value": "3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "data6",
        "type": "CheckBox",
        "values": [
            {
                "value": "2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the HTML on which this code operates.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be… **Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem**. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate the original data structure with [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#map) and transform it to the requested format. Use [`_.filter()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#map) or [`_.reject()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#reject) to remove sections without selected values ([plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/nlfyImr2TznJoKnFKNFS?p=preview)):

```
$scope.applyFilters = function() {
  var arr = _($scope.filters)
    .map(function(o, i) {
      var section = _.pick(o, ['name', 'type']);

      section.values = _(o.values)
        .filter(function(v, j) {
          return $scope.models['data' + (i + 1) + (j + 1)];
        })
        .map(_.partialRight(_.pick, 'value'))
        .value();

      return section;
    })
    .reject(function(o) { return _.isEmpty(o.values); })
    .value();

  console.log(arr);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)` to contains only the selected values in its respective object.

Just change your `applyFilters` to this:

```
 $scope.applyFilters = function() {
    var arr = [];
    _.map($scope.filters, function(d) {
      _.map(d.values, function(v) {
        var name = d.name + v.value;
        for (key in $scope.models) {
           if (key == name && $scope.models.hasOwnProperty(key) && $scope.models[key]) {
            arr.push({
              name: d.name,
              values: v
            });
          }
        }
      });
    });
    console.log(arr);
  };
```

plunker: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/waIwyXgEkdfPtybq

Hope it helps!